# Spring Neo4j Pass Node Property as Parameter

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to pass a property as a parameter.

I have tried this:

```
String get_interest="MATCH(user:User{id:{id}})-[watched:WATCHED]->(movie:Movie{title:{title}}) " +
        "MATCH(movie)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(category:Category) " +
        "MATCH(category)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(similarMovie:Movie) " +
        "WHERE NOT EXISTS((user) -[:WATCHED]->(similarMovie))" +
        "RETURN similarMovie Limit 20";
```

But it fails with this error:

```
"error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Cypher execution failed with code 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError': Invalid input '{': expected \"+\" or \"-\" (line 1, column 24 (offset: 23))
```

I have tried this and it worked:

```
String get_interest="MATCH(user:User{id:\"02331\"})-[watched:WATCHED]->(movie:Movie{title:\"The Mask\"}) " +
        "MATCH(movie)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(category:Category) " +
        "MATCH(category)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(similarMovie:Movie) " +
        "WHERE NOT EXISTS((user) -[:WATCHED]->(similarMovie))" +
        "RETURN similarMovie Limit 20";
```

But I want to pass other User ids and titles.

This is my Repository

```
@Query(get_interest)
Collection<Movie> getMovieByInterest(@Param("id") String id,
                                         @Param("title") String title);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Params are bound as variables. Variables are interpolated with dollar:

```
"MATCH(user:User{id:$id})-[watched:WATCHED]->(movie:Movie{title:$title})"
```